# Cloning a repository from Google Cloud Composer DAG

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

How can I clone from a cloud source respository and push the code to a repository in another GCP project from Google Cloud Composer?

I used the gcloud command to clone the code into the Composer Cloud Storage bucket and getting the following error:

> Cloning into '/home/airflow/gcsfuse/data/source_code'...
>
> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

The cause of the error is described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed-779171803.html)

Can this be done from the Composer environment?

Comment: Have you ensured that your environment's service account has access to the repo? Also, if you're doing this in a PythonOperator and pushing in the same step, you may want to clone into /tmp instead, as it doesn't seem like you need to have GCS on the path.

Comment: The environment's service account has access to the repo. I'm able to clone into /tmp and push the code to another repo. Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor Please consider posting your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ensured that your environment's service account has access to the repo? Also, if you're doing this in a PythonOperator and pushing in the same step, you may want to clone into /tmp instead, as it doesn't seem like you need to have GCS on the path.